# What is the correct word for "acronymed"?

Tags: single-word-requests, abbreviations, acronyms

First of all, I am not a native English speaker, so that's why I'm having an issue with this one.
I am under the impression that an abbreviation is the shortening of something, like boulevard = blvd, and acronyms is when you shorten longer words/sentences like World Trade Center = WTC. I don't know if I am mistaken here?

So I could say something like: "What is the full name of a street abbreviated blvd?"
But can you say the same thing with acronyms, like: "Which tall building that had a twin was acronymed WTC?"

It sounds really stupid to me. And I know I could probably just rephrase the questions. But does such adjective exist for acronym, or am I just an idiot, and acronyms and abbreviations can't be used interchangeably?

Comment: Well, first you'd need to "verb" the noun "acronym".  Then, since it's a neologism, you'd apply the usual English rules -- "acronymed" for past tense.

Comment: And then figure out how to not see it as “uh-’cron-uh-med”

Comment: *shortened to*?

Comment: Is there a problem with "Which tall building that had a twin had the acronym / abbreviation WTC?"  (An in-house search will reveal the conflicting definitions used for 'acronym'.) There is no verb from _acronym_ at the moment.

Comment: There is no "official" verb from the word "acronym". You can 'verb' it, as someone pointed out above, but it would sound like you're being cute/creative with your words. It's fine (even awesome, IMO) in informal speech/writing, but might be frowned on in a formal/professional setting. BTW, Isn't WTC technically an initialism? Aren't the letters pronounced separately? Something like NATO or MoMA would be acronyms.

Comment: @filistinist If it's not in a dictionary or other respectable source, it's non-standard, and can't be recommended felicitously on ELU. Note the 'U'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make something shorter by writing it with just a few of its letters is to contract it. Blvd is the shortened, abbreviated, or ***contracted***, form of boulevard.

When you abbreviate a long name or term using just its initials, you're making an **abbreviation**. Eg. the USA is an abbreviated way of saying the United States of America.

When such an abbreviation can be pronounced like a word, it's called an acronym. Eg. the United Nations Children's Fund is abbreviated to UNICEF, which can be pronounced like a word when speaking. So UNICEF is an **acronym**.